# Job getting JCL error, but I can't figure out what is wrong

Tags: jcl

[image: CODE]

This is what I currently have. I've tried so many different edits and I just can't figure out what's wrong

```
//TSOZA603 JOB 3ES10G10000012,'TSOZA60,MSGCLASS=Q,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),
// NOTIFY=&SYSUID,CLASS=A,REGION=2M
//STEP1    EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY
//IN       DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=D80WW.ES10V15.CNTL
//OUT      DD   DISP=SHR,DSN=TSOZA60.COPY.CNTL
//SYSPRINT DD   SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD   *
    COPY OUTDD=OUT,INDD=IN
    SELECT MEMBER=((JOBCARD,,R))
/*
```

the error code is:

> 22.21.39 JOB18870 $HASP165 TSOZA603 ENDED AT MVSCZ01 - JCL ERROR CN(INTERNAL)
> screenshot of [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDO47.jpg)

Comment: Usually the generic "JCL ERROR" message is accompanied by other messages pointing to the problem.  If there are any other messages please paste them into your question.

Comment: unfortunately, that's all it says. I edited the post to have a screenshot of the error message

Comment: If you look at the job in the spool, via SDSF or whichever third party product your shop uses, there may be more information.

Answer (score 0):

The screen shot at the top does not match the code sample below. Both have errors.

In the screen shot (black background), it should say `MSGLEVEL=(1,1)` (equal sign is missing).

In the code sample, the closing quote around TSOZA60 (the programmer's name) is missing. It has to be `3ES10G10000012,'TSOZA60',MSGCLASS=Q,`

Note that the system will also report a `JCL ERROR` when it cannot find one or more of the data sets from the `DD` statements.

Look at the job's output in SDSF or whatever tool you're working with.